# Degree of curve where matrix of polynomials has rank 1

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, intersection-theory

My question is about a step in Exercise 12.8 on page 442 of 3264 & All That by Eisenbud and Harris. Chapter 12 is about Porteous' formula.

The exercise reads: Let $A=(P_{i,j})$ be a $2 \times 3$ matrix whose entries $P_{i,j}$ are general polynomials of degree $a_{i,j}$ on $\mathbb{P}^3$. Assuming that $a_{1,j}+a_{2,k}=a_{1,k}+a_{2,j}$ for all $j$ and $k$--so that the minors of $A$ are homogeneous--what is the degree of the curve where $A$ has rank $1$?

Shuai Wang posted a solution on page 21 of this document https://www.math.columbia.edu/~tedd2013/intersectiontheory.pdf which seems correct, but I'm struggling to understand one step of it.

He claims that the curve where $A$ has rank $1$ is the degeneracy locus of the following bundle map:

$\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^3}(a_{22}) \oplus \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^3}(a_{12}) \to \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^3}(a_{11}+a_{22}) \oplus \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^3}(a_{12}+a_{22}) \oplus \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^3}(a_{12}+a_{23})$.

\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix}
    a_{22}  & a_{12}
\end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix}
    a_{11}       & a_{12} & a_{13} \\
    a_{21}       & a_{22} & a_{23}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

I have a few questions about this bundle map.

Why is $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^3}(a_{11}+a_{22}) \oplus \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^3}(a_{12}+a_{22}) \oplus \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^3}(a_{12}+a_{23})$ the target space of this map?

Why is the degeneracy locus of this map equal the locus of the maximal minors of $A$? The maximal minors of $A$ are $\{a_{11}a_{22}-a_{21}a_{12}, a_{11}a_{23}-a_{13}a_{21}, a_{12}a_{23}-a_{22}a_{13}   \}$ while the result of the matrix multiplication is

\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix}
    a_{22}  & a_{12}
\end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix}
    a_{11}       & a_{12} & a_{13} \\
    a_{21}       & a_{22} & a_{23}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
    a_{11}a_{22}+a_{21}a_{12}  & a_{12}a_{22}+a_{12}a_{22} & a_{22}a_{13}+a_{12}a_{23}
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{align*}

In general, how does one find a map of vector bundles such that its degeneracy locus is the locus of maximal minors of a given matrix? (If possible, it would be nice for the vector bundles to be written as sums of line bundles.)  This seems like an important tool for applying Porteus' formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you got confused with the map. Let's define a bundle map by right multiplication with 
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
    P_{11}       & P_{12} & P_{13} \\
    P_{21}       & P_{22} & P_{23}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
whose degrees are respectively$$ \begin{bmatrix}
    a_{11}       & a_{12} & a_{13} \\
    a_{21}       & a_{22} & a_{23}
\end{bmatrix}$$
Start taking $\begin{bmatrix}
    R  & S
\end{bmatrix}$ a section of $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^3}(a_{22}) \oplus \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^3}(a_{12})$. Then 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
    R  & S
\end{bmatrix} A = \begin{bmatrix}
    RP_{11}+SP_{21}  & RP_{12}+SP_{22} & RP_{13}+SP_{23}
\end{bmatrix} =: C
$$
The identity $a_{1,j}+a_{2,k}=a_{1,k}+a_{2,j}$ says that this map is well defined and the target is $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^3}(r) \oplus \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^3}(s)\oplus \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^3}(t)$, for some integers $r,s,t$.

These numbers are the corresponding degrees of the entries of $C$, so $r= a_{22}+a_{11}$, $s= a_{22}+a_{12}$ and $t= a_{22}+a_{13} = a_{12}+a_{23}  $.

Now you want to calculate the points $p\in \mathbb{P}^3$ such that the map $(x,y) \mapsto \begin{bmatrix}
    x  & y
\end{bmatrix}A(p)$  is not injective, the so called degenracy locus. This coincides with the vanishing of the minors of $A(p)$, hence the degeneracy locus of this bundle map is given by vanishing of the minors of $A$.